# Incorrect conversion from R Markdown to LaTeX

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

Why does the following R Markdown minimal (non)-working example not compile to PDF?

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \lhead{}
- \chead{}
- \rhead{The performance of new graduates}
- \lfoot{From: K. Grant}
- \cfoot{To: Dean A. Smith}
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Test
```

In particular, the problematic conversion happens to `-\lfoot{From: K. Grant}` and `-\cfoot{To: Dean A. Smith}`, as seen in the output `.tex` file:

```tex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{The performance of new graduates}
true
true
```

For some reason, both of these lines are converted to `true` causing

> LaTeX error: Missing `\begin{document}`

thereby preventing the document from compiling to PDF.

Changing `\lfoot` and `\cfoot` to just about anything else seems to lead to them being converted correctly. So what's going on here? I take it that there must be a problem with either `knitr` or `pandoc` in the conversion process.

<sup>NB: I'm not too familiar with R Markdown, and this is a follow-up question to [Headers and footers created in Fancyhead not shown in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226489/headers-and-footers-created-in-fancyhead-not-shown-in-pdf-using-knitr) on TeX.SX on Tom's behalf.</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:` character is the problem. `pandoc` seems to be trying to parse the `header-includes` content as if it were variables, and `:` is used to separate variables and values. It compiles if you quote the lines in question (don't forget, then, to escape the leading backslash)

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \lhead{}
- \chead{}
- \rhead{The performance of new graduates}
- "\\lfoot{From: K. Grant}"
- "\\cfoot{To: Dean A. Smith}"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Test
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem and that's not a solution anymore, unfortunately.

Comment: Worked for me in 2023. The double backslash mustn't be forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

Stitching the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139205/180108) with trial and error, I found that only by deleting the `title` key and using YAML pipe-denoted multiline string syntax would it compile:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes: |
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhead{}
   \fancyfoot{}
   \lhead{My Title}
   \rhead{My Note}
   \lfoot{\today}\rfoot{Page \thepage}
---
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using pandoc's [`raw_attribute` feature](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#generic-raw-attribute) (enabled by default) to mark the raw LaTeX section as such.  This is the most robust solution.

````
header-includes: |
   ```{=latex}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhead{}
   \fancyfoot{}
   \lhead{My Title}
   \rhead{My Note}
   \lfoot{\today}\rfoot{Page \thepage}
   ```
````