# Stop knitr "sanitizing" characters in header-includes

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am creating a document where some tables have some columns that benefit from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef) solution to forcing right-alignment of wrapped-text entries.

To implement that solution I include the following in my preamble:

```
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}}
```

To implement this with `knitr`, I tried:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}}
---
```

But this fails with error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> ...
>
> l.83 \newcolumntype{R}{[}1
>
> pandoc: Error producing PDF
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Examining the .tex output, it's clear what's gone wrong:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{[}1{]}\{\textgreater{}\{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\}p\{\#1\linewidth\}\}
```

`knitr` has converted `>` to `\textgreater{}`, `{` to `\{`, `}'` to `\}`, `[` to `{[}`, `]` to `{]}`, and `#` to `\#`. I of course want *none* of these automatic conversions.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009666/incorrect-conversion-from-r-markdown-to-latex) question addressed the same issue, but in that case there was a workaround that solved the issue (quoting in the YAML) -- quoting and escaping `\` produces the same output, quoting without escaping `\` produces an "unrecognized control sequence" error.

How can I get `knitr` not to manipulate my input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can (and should) use the `includes` option (see [documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#includes)). An extra benefit is that your LaTeX code will only be applied to the LaTeX output. If you use `header-includes` in the YAML metadata, it will be applied to all possible output formats, e.g. even when you compile Rmd to HTML.

BTW, **knitr** does not sanitize any characters in YAML. Pandoc does.

Comment: Awesome! I wish I had come across this before being suggested to use `header-includes`... Given the header is so short, it would be nice to create it directly inside the YAML instead of having to create a new file. Any way to do that?

Comment: To be honest, sometimes I feel I want this feature, too. But it is not possible for now.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, motivated by https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4473#issuecomment-419667477, is to escape LaTeX code from pandoc (note that I also changed the yaml multiline style to '|' for convenience):

````yaml
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{array}
  ```{=latex}
  \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}}
  ```
---
````